# SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException with multiple authentication schemes

Tags: asp.net-core

I have an Azure Active Directory with app registrations set up. I have a B2C tenant with app registrations and with multiple user flows set up.

In Startup.cs I have configured multiple authentication schemes like below.

```
services
    .AddAuthentication()
    .AddJwtBearer("Azure", options => 
    {
        options.Audience = "clientId";
        options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId";
    })
    .AddJwtBearer("AzureB2cCustomerSignIn", options => 
    {
        options.Audience = "clientIdInB2c";
        options.Authority = "https://tentantName.b2clogin.com/tenantName.onmicrosoft.com/userFlowName/v2.0";
    })
    .AddJwtBearer("AzureB2cCustomerSignUp", options => 
    {
        options.Audience = "clientIdInB2c";
        options.Authority = "https://tentantName.b2clogin.com/tenantName.onmicrosoft.com/userFlowName/v2.0";
    })
    .AddJwtBearer("AzureB2cEmployeeSignUpAndSignIn", options => 
    {
        options.Audience = "clientIdInB2c";
        options.Authority = "https://tentantName.b2clogin.com/tenantName.onmicrosoft.com/userFlowName/v2.0";
    });

services
    .AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .AddAuthenticationSchemes("Azure", "AzureB2cCustomerSignIn", "AzureB2cCustomerSignUp", "AzureB2cEmployeeSignUpAndSignIn")
            .Build();
    }
```

When I try to authenticate with a token from a B2C flow I'm getting the single error below. The application can continue, the API method is executed, everything works. But this severely clutters application insights with errors. And more importantly, most likely also hampers performance. I must be missing some configuration...

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException: IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match key: 
kid: 'System.String'.
Exceptions caught:
 'System.Text.StringBuilder'. 
token: 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken'.
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateSignature(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, SecurityToken& validatedToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler: Information: Azure was not authenticated. Failure message: IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Unable to match key: 
kid: 'System.String'.
Exceptions caught:
 'System.Text.StringBuilder'. 
token: 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken'.
```

It states that the token could not be validated against the authentication scheme I have configured for Azure Active Directory, which is obvious. Since it's a token coming from the B2C authentication flow, I do not even want it to try to authenticate using this authentication scheme. Logically, when I authenticate with a token coming from the AAD flow I get the `SecurityTokenSignatureKeyNotFoundException` three times.

How can I avoid this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution to the problem is to add a custom JwtBearerHandler which is aware of the issuer of the token, and only validates the token when the token issuer is the same as the authentication scheme issuer.

The code of the custom handler is below.

```
public class CustomJwtHandler : JwtBearerHandler
{
    public CustomJwtHandler(
        IOptionsMonitor<JwtBearerOptions> options,
        ILoggerFactory logger,
        UrlEncoder encoder,
        ISystemClock clock)
        : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
    {
    }

    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        var authenticationSchemeConfiguration = await this.Options.ConfigurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync(this.Context.RequestAborted);
        var jwt = this.ReadTokenFromHeader();
        var jwtHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        if (jwtHandler.CanReadToken(jwt))
        {
            var token = jwtHandler.ReadJwtToken(jwt);
            if (string.Equals(token.Issuer, authenticationSchemeConfiguration.Issuer, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                return await base.HandleAuthenticateAsync();
            }
            else
            {
                return AuthenticateResult.NoResult();
            }
        }

        return await base.HandleAuthenticateAsync();
    }

    private string ReadTokenFromHeader()
    {
        var authorization = Request.Headers["Authorization"].ToString();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(authorization))
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (authorization.StartsWith("Bearer ", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return authorization.Substring(7).Trim();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

The wireup of the custom handler is below. Note the additional service which must be added, without which the JwtBearerOptions in the custom handler is null, leading to a NullReferenceException when calling GetConfigurationAsync.

```
services
    .AddAuthentication()
    .AddScheme<JwtBearerOptions, CustomJwtHandler>("Azure", options => Configuration.Bind("AzureJwtBearerOptions", options))
    .AddScheme<JwtBearerOptions, CustomJwtHandler>("AzureB2cCustomerSignIn", options => Configuration.Bind("AzureB2cCustomerSignInJwtBearerOptions", options))
    .AddScheme<JwtBearerOptions, CustomJwtHandler>("AzureB2cCustomerSignUp", options => Configuration.Bind("AzureB2cCustomerSignUpJwtBearerOptions", options))
    .AddScheme<JwtBearerOptions, CustomJwtHandler>("AzureB2cEmployeeSignUpAndSignIn", options => Configuration.Bind("AzureB2cEmployeeSignUpAndSignInJwtBearerOptions", options))
    .Services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IPostConfigureOptions<JwtBearerOptions>, JwtBearerPostConfigureOptions>()); // Without this JwtBearerOptions.ConfigurationManager is null.
```