Add custom JwtBearerHandler to "AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi" in .net7
How does one wire a custom JwtBearerHandler in .NET7 to this:
 builder.Services.AddAuthentication() .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration);

Alternatively, how would I translate the previous statement into this
builder.Services
.AddAuthentication()
.AddScheme<JwtBearerOptions, CustomJwtHandler>("AzureAd", options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))

like they do in this example in the answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/68258618/441365

You could directly replace built-in JwtBearerHandler by CustomJwtBearerHandler using DI.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
builder.Services.AddTransient<JwtBearerHandler, CustomJwtBearerHandler>();

You could test logic like following which will work in the "MicrosoftIdentityWebApi" pipleline.
    public class CustomJwtBearerHandler : JwtBearerHandler
    {
        public CustomJwtBearerHandler(
            IOptionsMonitor<JwtBearerOptions> options,
            ILoggerFactory logger,
            System.Text.Encodings.Web.UrlEncoder encoder,
            ISystemClock clock)
            : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
        {
        }

        protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
        {
            // Perform your custom authentication logic here
            var result = await base.HandleAuthenticateAsync();

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                // Custom logic, e.g., logging or additional validation
                var ticket = result.Ticket;

                // Example: Reject if a custom claim is missing
                if (!ticket.Principal.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "custom-claim"))
                {
                    return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Missing required custom claim.");
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }

